# Array of objects to a single object containing all said objects Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am trying to transform the below Array of Objects input:

```
[
 {
    "Id": "3",
    "Code": "4190484",
    "Expense": "Huge Expense "   
 },
 {
    "Id": "4",
    "Code": "271",
    "Expense": "Big Expense"   
 },
 {
    "Id": "3",
    "Code": "433",
    "Expense": "No Expense"   
 } 
]
```

to this Output of a single object:

```
{
    "Id": "3",
    "Code": "4190484",
    "Expense": "Huge Expense ",
    "Id": "4",
    "Code": "271",
    "Expense": "Big Expense",
    "Id": "3",
    "Code": "433",
    "Expense": "No Expense"
}
```

How would you accomplish this in Dataweave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the reduce() function but be warned that using duplicate keys in JSON is implementation dependent. I think it is a bad design to use duplicate keys in JSON. It might lead to unexpected behaviors. Some implementations might ignore the duplicates. For example DataWeave will return only one Id of the resulting object with `payload.Id`.

If even after what I mentioned you still want to go ahead it this is an example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
// I don't recommend to use duplicate keys
payload reduce  ((item, acc = {}) -> acc ++ item)
```

Comment: I was just trying to figure out a way to do this. Good point about the complexity around duplicate keys.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the [dynamic elements](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#dynamic_elements) feature of the language:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{(payload)}
```

Like @aled explained in his answer, you should not be using duplicate keys in JSON.

Comment: That's interesting. I see it works but it is not clear to me why.

Comment: It the `{(payload)}` when an object has an expression between parenthesis what it means is that the result of the expression inside the parenthesis will be expanded in the upper object. This is the best solution

Comment: I feel like this feature needs more documentation to be clear how it applies to different use cases.

Comment: @aled it is very similar to the javascript spread operator if you're familiar with that. But yes, I agree - it isn't something covered well in the docs, and it is extremely useful when building objects/arrays